# How can a node read a role file?

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

Say we have a node named ***mycomputer***. And it has a role in it's run_list say `myrole`.

Now, the ***mycomputer*** wants to access and read the role file which is present in it's run_list.

Is there a way to do this ?

---

I tried

```
knife role show myrole
```

As it doesn't have knife.rb and user-key.pem file (.chef directory) so it cannot access it.

---

Please let me know if there is a way to access the role file viz. `myrole`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you write that the **node** "mycomputer" has the given role in its run list applied, the contained information is kind of "automatically" available. To be precise, the attributes (and additional run list entries) are automatically merged with other attributes (from environments, cookbooks, etc).

So if your role "myrole" defines the following attributes:

```rb
default_attributes 'apache2' => {
  'listen_ports' => [ '80', '443' ]
}
```

this will be accessible during the chef run on your node via

```rb
node['apache2']['listen_ports']
```

Attributes are fundamental concept of chef and should solve your problem to define some information in a role and read it during the chef run on some node.

You find more information about that concept in the docs about [Attribute Precedence](https://docs.chef.io/roles.html#attribute-precedence). There's not really a way to read the plain file - if you really think you need to do so, you're using Chef in a wrong way. Better state with your next question, what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: My requirement was to access the attributes from the Role file. Yes, you are right that they get merged with the attributes in the *node*. I overlooked this part and was indeed using "Chef in a wrong way". Thanks for patiently helping me with this :)